# Solutions To The Differential Form Of Snell's Law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

In the standard version of [Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law), there are rays, which cannot extend beyond a certain point (while satisfying the law), hence are reflected ([total internal reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection)).  I wonder if this is also the case for the [differential form](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Optics/Geometric_Optics_(Tatum)/01%3A_Reflection_and_Refraction/1.08%3A_Differential_Form_of_Snell%27s_Law) of the law (e.g. when assuming that the optical density function is smooth or Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbf{R}^3$ or $\mathbf{R}^n$).

If not, how does the approximation of a non-continuous optical density function (where total internal reflection takes place) by a sufficiently smooth one look like, in terms of solutions?  Can solutions be bounded, e.g. a ray going in a circle?

Comment: My gut says that in the differential form, it is difficult to get the ray to actually _turn around_ (assuming the refrasctive index is only a function of vertical position).

Comment: I assume the index to be a function of $\mathbf{R}^3$ (although $\mathbf{R}^n$ would be interesting as well).  But yes, I think you are right, there must be some discrete step when looking at a smooth index approximating a non-continuous one.

Comment: But note that total internal reflection doesn't mean that the ray turns around, it only happens when the angle is obtuse enough (depending on the refraction index ofc).

Comment: If the ray doesn't turn around, then it exits the medium, and there is only minor reflection. At any rate it's certainly not _total internal_ reflection. That requires reflection, meaning the ray must turn around and go down into the medium again. (When I say "turn around", I don't specifically mean $180^\circ$.)

Comment: Ah, with turn around I meant 180 degrees, but yes, the ray is reflected along some surface.  But it would also be total internal reflection if the ray only changes direction by, say, 1 degree.

Comment: As long as it goes from moving upwards to moving downwards (looking at the picture in your libretexts link), then yeah, that can reasonably be called total internal reflection regaardless of how many degrees it actually turns. And I don't see that happening with a continuous refractive index that only depends on height.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe an interesting question, how would a very small but smooth transition between two materials make the ray behave?  As you say, it cannot get reflected, so instead of total internal reflection, I guess it would end up traveling along the material boundary?  But what about ways where TIR does not take place, would the ray get bent in a similar angle to the discrete case?